# Class "App\Http\Controllers\User" not found

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-8

So I was fetching data from my database to print in a table however, it says that

> Class "App\Http\Controllers\User" not found.

Here is the controller and here is how I will print the data

```
public function directory()
    {
        $dashboardTitle = "Directory";
    $isCurrent = "Directory";
    $users = User::all();
    return view('dashboard.directory', [
        'dashboardTitle' => $dashboardTitle,
        'isCurrent' => $isCurrent,
        'users' => $users
    ]);
    }
```

table to print at

```
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                        <th> Picture </th>
                                            <th>Name</th>
                                            <th>Email</th>
                                            <th>User type</th>
                                            <th>Birthdate</th>
                                            <th>Contact number</th>
                                            <th>Created time</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        @foreach($users as $user)
                                        <tr>
                                           <td>{{ $user->profile_image }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $user->user_type }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $user->bdate }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $user->contact_no}}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $user->created_at }}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </thead>
                                    <tfoot>

                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the top off your controller add

Laravel 8+

```
use App\Models\User;
```

Laravel <=7

```
use App\User;
```

Comment: ohh didn't notice that  did not use the user, Thanks!